# how to implement scss code in to html? for example http://www.bypeople.com/css-simple-hamburguer-menu-icon/

Tags: html, css

How to inplement this effects on my html?

effect will on this "http://www.bypeople.com/css-simple-hamburguer-menu-icon/"

Comment: in this effect use scss ? how to execute?

Comment: No this is not how it works... Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. Neither is it considered to be a good question if it is just a question with a link! Show what you have tried so far and ask specific questions!

Comment: what i do mr  geisterfurz007 ? you did not recognise the question.

Comment: who will consider you expert on this site? simple question you cant recognize

Comment: and a third class process for asking question from stack overflow. please mak it realible, simple not difficult.